# Eliminate Facebook Likes for certain URLS on WordPress Site

Tags: php, wordpress, facebook

I have a plugin where we are pulling number of shares on social networks. However we are now pulling in articles from Bloomberg using canonical URLS and it's counting their facebook likes and shares as well.

We use these numbers to power a "Top Trending" widget. Obviously, their site is huge. So that means articles from Bloomberg are going to take over our top trending posts widget.

Is there a way to not count the number of facebook shares and likes from the bloomberg article and only count those that are native to our site? Or, as I suspect, shouldn't it only be pulling in shares that are based on our own API? Kinda confused.

Here's our current code for Facebook count collecting.

```
function getFacebook() {



    $query = "SELECT total_count FROM link_stat WHERE url = '$this->url'";

    $url = "https://api.facebook.com/method/fql.query?format=json&query=".rawurlencode($query);



    $ch = curl_init();

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 2);

    $response = curl_exec($ch);

    curl_close ($ch);



    $response = json_decode($response, 1);



    if ( empty( $this->stats['facebook'] ) ) {

        $this->stats['facebook'] = 0;

    }



    $this->stats['facebook'] = !empty($response[0]['total_count']) ? $response[0]['total_count'] : $this->stats['facebook'];

}
```

Comment: This should not even work any more, because FQL is gone. And no, there is no way to get likes or shares that were made via your app/site, you can only get the global counts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is assuming the value of `$this->url` is the URL of their article, and `www.bloomberg.com` is their domain, but you could test for the presence of their domain in the url then make it `0` and return before the rest of the statement is executed if it is:

```
function getFacebook() {

    if(strstr($this->url,'www.bloomberg.com')) {
      $this->stats['facebook'] = 0;
      return;
    }

    // rest of code for this function...
```

Comment: So you think I should just add this at the top of the function and it should eliminate any facebook likes from urls that contain www.bloomberg.com?

Above the $query I mean?